# How to update a ColumnDataSource data for a MultiLine glyph?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, bokeh, multiline

I am trying to create a Bokeh application that plots multiple time-series, and allows the user to select a subset of the time-series using a `CheckboxButtonGroup` widget.  I would like to change the displayed graphs from python, rather than attempting to hide/un-hide lines on the javascript side.  I have attempted to do this by adding a multi-line and changing the values in its data source from a callback function.  This works fine when I change the contents of the time series, or when I remove a time series, but as soon as I attempt to add a time-series to the multi-line, I get an error on the javascript side (the chrome console prints `Bokeh: Error handling message`).

To be specific, I have a pandas data frame with a `data` column indexed by bucket names and timestamps:

```
data = pandas.DataFrame(...)
buckets = data.index.levels[0]
timestamps = data.index.levels[1]
```

I have a multi-line graph and a control:

```
plot = bokeh.plotting.Figure(x_axis_type = "datetime")
multiline = plot.multi_line(xs = [], ys = [])
bucketsControl = bokeh.models.widgets.CheckboxButtonGroup(labels = list(buckets))
```

And I have a callback function that updates the data source and is triggered by the control:

```
def update(value):
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for bucketIndex in bucketsControl.active:
        bucketName = bucketsControl.labels[bucketIndex]
        bucketData = data.loc[bucketName]
        series = bucketData["data"]
    xs.append(series.index.values)
    ys.append(series.values)
    multiline.data_source.data["xs"] = xs
    multiline.data_source.data["ys"] = ys

bucketsControl.on_click(update)
```

I don't know for sure what's causing the problem here, but I've taken a look at the web socket traffic going between the Bokeh server and the web-browser when I attempt to add another time-series, and I see that it results in two `ModelChanged` updates: the first one adds another list to `xs`, and the seconds one adds a list to `ys`.  I suspect that the BokehJS client isn't able to handle that first update, where it has one more x series than y series.

Is there a way to make this multi-line update work? Or, is there another way to update the structure of the plot from python (e.g. adding a whole new line to the plot, rather than changing the data-source of an existing glyph)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you update the data source twice. You can update it only once by:

```
data = dict(xs=xs, ys=ys)
multiline.data_source.data = data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**patch**](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.sources.ColumnDataSource.patch) to update only the new data, minimizing the data that is going to be sent to the front-end

- To update a entire line:

  ```
  source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
      xs=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
      ys=[[1, 2, 3, 4.2, 2.2, 0.5]],
  ))
  source.patch({
      'ys' : [(0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])]
  })
  ```
- To update line fragments:

  ```
  source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
      xs=[np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])],
      ys=[np.array([1, 2, 3, 4.2, 2.2, 0.5])],
  ))
  source.patch({
      'ys' : [([0, slice(3, 6)], np.array([4, 5, 6]))]
  })
  ```
- There is a hacky way to remove the whole, because this is not supported by bokeh

  ```
  source.patch({
      'ys' : [(0,[''])],     # or 'ys' : [(0,numpy.array([numpy.nan]))], 
  })
  ```

Also, you can update many columns at the same time just adding keys to the patch dictionary